# Primefaces: ContextMenu does not appear in overlayPanel

Tags: java, primefaces, tree, contextmenu, overlay

I try to add a contextMenu in a tree to perform a custom action. This tree is implemented inside an overlaypanel. What i observed is that the contextMenu only appears in random situations like after selecting and unselecting some elements on the tree. Any Idea?

```html
<p:overlayPanel id="advancedSearchPanel" 
    styleClass="ui-advanced-search-overlay"
    for="advancedSearch" 
    hideEffect="fade" 
    my="right top" 
    widgetVar="advancedSearchPanelWidgetVar" > 
        <ui:include src="/search/advancedSearch-form.xhtml"/>  
</p:overlayPanel>
```

advancedSearch-form

```html
<p:panelGrid  id="panelAdvanced" styleClass="borderless">
...
    <p:row> 
        <p:column colspan="4"> 
            <p:outputLabel value="#{text['searchForm.classifiers']}" for="treeClassifier" styleClass="paddingLabelGrid"/>

            <p:contextMenu id="contextSearch" for="treeClassifier">
                <p:menuitem value="Escolha todos" update=":searchForm:treeClassifier" actionListener="#{navBarController.displaySelectedSingle}"/>
            </p:contextMenu>

            <p:tree id="treeClassifier" 
                value="#{navBarController.rootClassifier}" 
                var="node" selectionMode="checkbox" 
                selection="#{navBarController.selectedClassifiers}"
                style="height: 200px;width: 540px; margin-bottom: 0px; overflow: auto" 
                propagateSelectionDown="false"
                propagateSelectionUp="false">

                    <p:ajax event="select" update=":searchForm:btnSearch"/> 
                    <p:ajax event="unselect" update=":searchForm:btnSearch"/>     

                    <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
                         <h:outputText value="#{node.description}(#{node.code})"/> 
                    </p:treeNode>  
            </p:tree>
        </p:column>   
    </p:row>
...
```

Comment: Please explain a lot of information. Are you want to change tree whenever contextMenu has been selected?

Comment: Why are you silent, the code works?

Comment: No, I try your code but the function onContextMenu is never reached.

Comment: Strangely, I wrote this code is straight and it worked. Used primefaces 5.1. Show me more of your code and I'll try to run it and find out. Show all code file advancedSearch-form.xhtml

Comment: Now i can acess to onContextMenu function but the menu only appear randomly. Could be caused by z-index?

Comment: Hard to say, try to remove your css styles and classes, and then check. Because I have tried without your ccs styles and menu appear every right click. Or try to place the <ui:include src="/search/advancedSearch-form.xhtml"/> outside <p: overlayPanel /> tag to isolate the problem.

Comment: The problem was the z-index. I put a style class in the contextMenu element with a higher z-index and the itemMenu appears. :)

Comment: @tech4 it's great. I hope my advice helped you in figuring out your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like that:

my advancedSearch-form.xhtml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">      

<h:form id="searchForm">
    <p:panelGrid  id="panelAdvanced" styleClass="borderless">
       <p:row> 
          <p:column colspan="4"> 
               <p:contextMenu id="contextSearch" for="treeClassifier">
                                <p:menuitem value="Escolha todos" update="treeClassifier" actionListener="#{treeView.displaySelectedSingle}"/>
                </p:contextMenu>
                <p:tree id="treeClassifier" value="#{treeView.root}" var="node" selectionMode="checkbox" selection="#{treeView.selectedClassifiers}" 
                            style="height: 200px;width: 540px; margin-bottom: 0px; overflow: auto" 
                            propagateSelectionDown="false" 
                            propagateSelectionUp="false">
                                <p:ajax event="select"  global="false" listener="#{treeView.reset}" /> 
                                <p:ajax event="unselect"  global="false" listener="#{treeView.reset}" />     
                                <p:ajax event="contextMenu" global="false" listener="#{treeView.onContextMenu}"/>     
                                <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{node.nodeName}"/> 
                                </p:treeNode>  
                </p:tree>
           </p:column>   
       </p:row>
       </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>           
</ui:composition>
```

And my bean:

```java
@Component(value="treeView")
@Scope(value = "session")
public class TreeView implements Serializable {

    private TreeNode[] selectedClassifiers;

    public TreeNode[] getSelectedClassifiers() {
        return selectedClassifiers;
    }

    public void setSelectedClassifiers(TreeNode[] selectedClassifiers) {
        this.selectedClassifiers = selectedClassifiers;
    }

    private TreeNode selectedClassifier;

    public void reset(){
        selectedClassifier = null;
    }

    public void displaySelectedSingle(){
        if(selectedClassifier != null){
             List<TreeNode> selected = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
             for(int i=0; i < selectedClassifiers.length; i++){
                 selected.add(selectedClassifiers[i]);
                 if(selectedClassifiers[i].equals(selectedClassifier))
                     selected.addAll(selectionRecursive(selectedClassifier));
             }
             selectedClassifiers = selected.toArray(new TreeNode[selected.size()]);
        }

    }

    public void onContextMenu(NodeSelectEvent event){
     selectedClassifier = event.getTreeNode();
    }

    public List<TreeNode> selectionRecursive(TreeNode node){

        List<TreeNode> selected = node.getChildren();

        for(TreeNode child : node.getChildren()){
            selected.addAll(selectionRecursive(child));
            child.setSelected(true);
        }

        return selected;
    }
}
```

Method selectionRecursive(TreeNode node) need debug but in my case all work great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you really want to achieve, but:

You are using 2 features of the tree component.

- Checkbox (multiple) selection
- Context menu *on nodes*

Use of both features at the same time is not currently supported bt Primefaces. Whenever you right-click a node, the contextMenu shows up, then the node is selected/deselected. The contextMenu does not shows up if you click outside a node (container background or between nodes)

If you want a single contextMenu for the whole tree (ie Select All, Unselect All, Select whatever...) so just remove the ***for*** attribute on *contextMenu* :

instead of :

```
<p:contextMenu id="contextSearch" for="treeClassifier">
```

just write

```
<p:contextMenu id="contextSearch">
```

In this way, the *contextMenu* appears wherever you right-click on the container (`p:column` in your case).

Comment: Yes, i want the two features performed on the node.  The checkbox is to select nodes in every level but not the childs. The contextMenu is to select the node and its children. I try what you said to do but nothing happens :/